# Creating D3 map of ellipse envelope data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geospatial

I have this dataset which has ellipses, more specifically ellipse "envelopes." I was wondering if someone had advice on how I could draw these on a D3 map. I already have a map setup with mercator projection. [This stackoverflow answer has a createEllipse function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50596892/838158) which got me close, but I want to make sure I am interpreting the data correctly.

I plugged in the major/minor axis values of the ellipse from the data, and used the azimuth for the rotation, would this be correct? I also don't really understand the "envelope" part. How do several ellipses in each zone create a single contiguous shape?

Any advice would be appreciated.

[image]

```js
  const margin  = {top:0, right:0, bottom:0, left:0},
        width   = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height  = 800  - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  const svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', '100%')
      .attr('height', '100%')
      .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width + margin.left + margin.right} ${height + margin.top + margin.bottom}`);

  const chart = svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

  //a/b are ellipse axes, x/y is center
  const createEllipse = function createEllipse(a, b, x = 0, y = 0, rotation = 0) {
    let k = Math.ceil(36 * (Math.max(a/b,b/a))); // sample angles
    let coords = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
      let angle = Math.PI*2 / k * i + rotation;
      let r = a * b / Math.sqrt(a*a*Math.sin(angle)*Math.sin(angle) + b*b*Math.cos(angle)*Math.cos(angle));
      coords.push(getLatLong([x,y],angle,r));
    }
    return { 'type':'Polygon', 'coordinates':[coords] };
  }

  const getLatLong = function getLatLong(center,angle,radius) {
    let rEarth = 6371; // kilometers
    x0 = center[0] * Math.PI / 180; // convert to radians.
    y0 = center[1] * Math.PI / 180;
    let y1 = Math.asin( Math.sin(y0)*Math.cos(radius/rEarth) + Math.cos(y0)*Math.sin(radius/rEarth)*Math.cos(angle) );
    let x1 = x0 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(angle)*Math.sin(radius/rEarth)*Math.cos(y0), Math.cos(radius/rEarth)-Math.sin(y0)*Math.sin(y1));
    y1 = y1 * 180 / Math.PI;
    x1 = x1 * 180 / Math.PI;
    return [x1,y1];
  } 


  d3.json('https://media.journalism.berkeley.edu/upload/2019/11/kazakhstan.json').then((data) => {

      const ellipses = [
        {lat: 48.6,    lng: 64.7,     axis_x: 30, axis_y: 16, azimuth: 26.5, area_hectar: 0.0713,  zone: 'U1'},
        {lat: 48.625,  lng: 64.625,   axis_x: 30, axis_y: 16, azimuth: 26.5, area_hectar: 0.0713,  zone: 'U1'},
        {lat: 48.366,  lng: 65.44166, axis_x: 50, axis_y: 30, azimuth: 40,   area_hectar: 0.11775, zone: 'U2'},
        {lat: 48.85,   lng: 65.61666, axis_x: 20, axis_y: 22, azimuth: 29,   area_hectar: 0.17584, zone: 'U3'},
        {lat: 48.9333, lng: 65.8,     axis_x: 22, axis_y: 22, azimuth: 28,   area_hectar: 0.17584, zone: 'U3'},
        {lat: 48.9166, lng: 66.05,    axis_x: 50, axis_y: 20, azimuth: 38,   area_hectar: 0.17584, zone: 'U3'},
        {lat: 48.9166, lng: 65.68333, axis_x: 20, axis_y: 22, azimuth: 29,   area_hectar: 0.17584, zone: 'U3'},
        {lat: 49,      lng: 65.86666, axis_x: 22, axis_y: 22, azimuth: 29,   area_hectar: 0.17584, zone: 'U3'}
      ]

      const projection = d3.geoMercator()
        .fitExtent([[0,0],[width,height]], data)

      const path = d3.geoPath()
        .projection(projection);


      chart.selectAll('path')
        .data(data.features)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('d',  path)
        .attr('stroke', 'black')
        .attr('strok-width', '1px')
        .attr('fill', 'none');

      chart.selectAll(".ellipses")
        .data(ellipses.map((d) => createEllipse(d.axis_x, d.axis_y, d.lng, d.lat, d.azimuth)))
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', path)
        .attr('stroke', 'black')
        .attr('stroke-width', '1px')
        .attr('fill', 'orange');

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are interpreting results almost right.

One error which I fixed is that your code doesn't consider the azimuth.

Another possible issue may be related to the axes. In the table provided they are named as "axis dimensions" which sound like an ellipse dimensions, while createEllipse function takes radiuses as params.
Please, have a look at the zoomed in [visualization](https://bl.ocks.org/Dmitra/75682a04073ee5c9fd8365227c2520f1) with above mentioned issues fixed. Tooltip on hover is added for the reference.

Third issue is arguable and depends on the data format established in the table. I mean that x doesn't always mean longitude and y - latitude. But logically it seems that ellipses longer values ("x" values are bigger or equal to "y" values) should correspond to horizontal direction.

As a side note: precision of visualization is also affected by the usage of approximated Earth radius but that is minor.

By "envelope" here is probably meant that ellipse circumscibe certain area of interest which lies inside, considering the fact that area values given are much smaller than the area of ellipse.

Comment: This helps immensely. Thank you for the reply and the code sample! I'm getting more info on the dataset. (It's data on falling rocket debris) So, I believe the envelope is the region in which all of the ellipses are contained.